# Access and change data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Little weather forecast app I'm working on. I've been trying to get the temperature to change from Celsius to Fahrenheit upon hovering over it, but all the changes I make either don't change the value or erase the line entirely. I'd like to learn to use the data attribute if possilble

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var long;
    var lat;

        $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://ip-api.com/json",   function(data2){ //access RESTFUL geo location API & set lattitude.longitude
            lat=data2.lat;
            long=data2.lon;

    var api = "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&appid=de61ccfbde0405f57d64dbb53323fccf&units=metric";
    //Access weather API

        $.getJSON(api, function(data){

            var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon; //get Icon from API related to current weather conditions
            var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+iconCode+".png";
            var tempCel = data.main.temp;
            $(".heading").append("<h2>"+data.name+","+data.sys.country+"</h2>");
            $(".message").append("<h4 id='tempData' data-temp='" + tempCel + "'>Current Temperature: "+tempCel+"&#8451</h4>");
            $(".message").append("<h4>Conditions: "+data.weather[0].main+"</h4>");
                // $("#reveal").on('click', function(){ //click button
                //  data.main.tempData //on click convert temperature to farenheight
                // });
            $(".message").append("<img id='conditions' src="+iconUrl+">");

            $("#tempData").hover(function(){
                $("#tempData").fadeToggle('slow', function(){

                });
            });
            console.log(data);
        });     
        });
    //$("#reveal").on("click", function(){
  //});
});
```

Comment: Just use attr method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at below code. Hope this will help you:

```
$.getJSON(api, function(data){

    var iconCode = data.weather[0].icon; //get Icon from API related to current weather conditions
    var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/"+iconCode+".png";
    var tempCel = data.main.temp;
    var tempFar = Math.round(parseFloat(tempCel) * 9 / 5 + 32); //calculating the temp in Fahrenheit

    $(".heading").append("<h2>"+data.name+","+data.sys.country+"</h2>");

    //setting the both temp in Cel and Far as a data attr which can be used in hover event listener
    $(".message").append("<h4 id='tempData' data-temp-cel='" + tempCel + "' data-temp-far='" + tempFar + "'>Current Temperature: "+tempCel+"&#8451</h4>");
    $(".message").append("<h4>Conditions: "+data.weather[0].main+"</h4>");

    $(".message").append("<img id='conditions' src="+iconUrl+">");

});         

//attaching the hover effect
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var tempInFar = $(this).data('temp-far');
        $(this).html("Current Temperature: "+tempInFar+"&#8457;"); //setting the inner html to show temp in Fahrenheit
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var tempInCel = $(this).data('temp-cel');
        $(this).html("Current Temperature: "+tempInCel+"&#8451;"); //setting the inner html to show temp in Celsius
    }
}, "#tempData");
```

Comment: Thank you! 2 questions though. 1) is it necessary to still use the data attributes if you just change the html using the tempCel and tempFar variable's value? 2) Can you explain the very last part to me with "#tempData"?

Comment: @DavidLett - 1) Yes; its required to use `data-` attr to store temperature data because HTML will be getting formed via  `$.getJSON` and user may hover on HTML element may be lets say after 2 min. Also there may be one or more temp data that can be shown on same page via this code. So to make this solution generic its better to go with `data-` approach. 2) `$(document).on({ ... },"#tempData");` is the way to attach event handler to the DOM element which may or may not be preset at the moment in your HTML. In our case we are building the DOM dynamically. thats why we have used this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try appending a div on hover to show the data.

```
$("#tempData").hover(function(){
        var tempIn = (tempCel * 1.8) + 32;
        $('<div />', {
                'class' : 'tip',
                text : "Temp in Farenheit: " + tempIn + " F",
                css : {
                    position: 'fixed' 
                }
            }).appendTo(this);
        },function(){ 
             $('.tip', this).remove();
        });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/96b3ca98/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>` element as child of `<h4>` to display temparature text. Set `@charset` to `"UTF-8"` at `css`; at `:hover`, `:after`, at `#tempData` element set `content` to  `attr()` with `data-temp` as parameter; set `span` to `display:none` at `#tempData` `:hover`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var long;
  var lat;

  $.getJSON("/path/to/resource", function(data2) { //access RESTFUL geo location API & set lattitude.longitude
    lat = data2.lat;
    long = data2.lon;

    var api = "/path/to/resource/1?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + long + "&appid=de61ccfbde0405f57d64dbb53323fccf&units=metric";
    //Access weather API

    $.getJSON(api, function(data) {

      var c = data.main.temp;
      var f = Math.floor(c * 1.8 + 32);
      var h4 = $("<h4></h4>", {
          id: "tempData",
          html: "Current Temperature: <span>" + c + "&#8451;</span></h4>",
          "data-temp": f
        })
        .appendTo("body");
    });
  });
});
```

```
@charset "UTF-8";
 #tempData:hover:after {
  content: attr(data-temp) "\2109";
}
#tempData:hover span {
  display: none;
}
```